# Can a chain reorg happen on Solana?

Tags: mainnet, fork

On Ethereum and other chains, a chain can split into "forks" and Validators then have to decide which path to go. Can that happen on Solana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly! This happens all the time as validators figure out the best fork to vote on.  As a simple example, if you have 5 validators, A, B, C, D, and E:

- A produces block 1 on fork 0
- B and C receive it and vote on it, D and E do not receive it
- B produces block 2 on 1
- A and C receive it and vote on it, D and E do not receive it
- D produces block 3 on 0
- A, B, and C receive it and DO NOT vote on it, E receives it and DOES

A, B, and C are on one fork, while D and E are on another.  Through the voting rules, D and E can eventually switch to go onto the other fork.

You can read more about Solana's implementation of PBFT at https://solana.com/news/tower-bft--solana-s-high-performance-implementation-of-pbft